# java interface inheritance conflicting methods

Tags: java

I am learning java and confused about interface inheritance. example from a book

```
 public interface Singer {
      void sing();
      void setRate(double rate);
      double getRate();  
  }  

  public interface Player {
      void play();
      void setRate(double rate);
      default double getRate() {
         return 300.0;
      }
  }

public interface SingerPlayer extends Singer, Player{
      // Override the getRate() method with a default method that calls the
      // Player superinterface getRate() method
     @Override
     default double getRate() {
          double playerRate = Player.super.getRate();
          double singerPlayerRate = playerRate * 3.5;
          return singerPlayerRate;
     }
 }


public class Employee implements Singer, SingerPlayer {

}
```

The books says Employee will inherit `SingerPlayer.setRate()` method because it overrides the `Singer.setRate()` method.

I do not see where it overrides this method.

Comment: By default, methods in interface are abstract and abstract methods do not specify a body. So first of all you have to correct 'Player' interface.

Comment: @Kartic Default methods in interfaces are a thing now http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_default_methods.htm

Comment: Oh, yeah! My mistake. Got to know just now.

Comment: Player interface has default method getRate and the compiler does not complain about that. I understand default methods.

Comment: I agree that at the moment `SingerPlayer` does not override `setRate()`. Maybe the book just meant that, in the event that it did override that method, then `Employee` would inherit that overridden version. Just checking, but does the book definitely say `setRate()` and not `getRate()`? Could be a misreading (happens to me a lot), or even a typo in the book.

Comment: @jonhopkins. Thanks very much, I think its typo from a book. I am using beginning Java fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

`getRate()` in SingerPlayer will override `getRate()` in Singer. And SingerPlayer inherits `getRate()`, `sing()` and `play()`.

Comment: Which setRate method does Employee inherit?

Comment: A class has to provide a body. And since setRate is the same in Both interfaces Employee needs to only implement void setRate(double rate).